# Overload [] python operator and chaining methods using a memory reference

Tags: python, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload `[] (__getitem__)` Python operator and chain methods using the initial memory reference.

Imagine I have a class `Math` that accepts a list of integer numbers, like this:

```
class Math(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        assert(all([isinstance(item, int) for item in list(args)]))
        self.list = list(args)

    def add_one(self):
        for index in range(len(self.list)):
            self.list[index] += 1
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
instance = Math(1,2,3,4,5)
instance[2:4].add_one()
```

After executing this code `instance.list` should be `[1,2,4,5,5]`, is this possible?

I know I could do something like `add_one(2,4)`, but this is not the style of API I would like to have if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Winston mentions, you need to implement an auxiliary object:

```
class Math(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.list = list(args)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return MathSlice(self, i)

class MathSlice(object):
    def __init__(self, math, slice):
        self.math = math
        self.slice = slice

    def add_one(self):
        for i in xrange(*self.slice.indices(len(self.math.list))):
            self.math.list[i] += 1


instance = Math(1,2,3,4,5)
instance[2:4].add_one()

print instance.list
```

How you share the math object with the MathSlice object depends on what you want the semantics to be if the math object changes.

Comment: `xrange(*self.slice.indices(len(self.math.list)))` feels awfully unpythonic. Is there a better way?

Comment: Also, you're mixing `self.fields` and `self.list`

Comment: @Eric: I removed the unneeded Math.add_one, and yes that xrange(*...) seems awfully cumbersome, but I don't know a shorter way.

Comment: Maybe `itertools.islice()` could be used to make a more "Pythonic" `add_one()` method.

Comment: Thanks Ned for your answer, very helfpul, let me know if you find a more pythonic way of solving add_one.

Comment: You could do `self.math.list[self.slice] = [x + 1 for x in self.math.list[self.slice]]`

Answer (score 5):

Numpy does something like this.

The `__getitem__` method will recieve a `slice` object. See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html for details. You'll need to return a new object, but implement that object such that it modifies the original list.

Comment: Thanks Winston for you answer. I'm accepting Ned's answer, because he's giving more implementation details and I think other users will find it more helpful. But I appreciate your answer.